# sort_values arranging values wrong

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a few columns Client ID, Prd No, Prd Weight. I made Client ID an index column as part of the process of transforming the data from wide to long using the wide_to_long method.

When I apply the sort_values method to the Prd No column, the arrangement is weird. It arranges it as 1, 10, 100, 101, 2, 20, 200....etc. How I want the data arranged is 1, 2, 3, 4...

I've tried all sorts of things, including explicitly changing the Prd No to an integer type using the astype() method, but no luck.

What could I be doing wrong? Is it a setting or version of Pandas I am using? Help, anyone?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("new_export.csv")

df1 = pd.wide_to_long(df,['diameterbh', 'base_diam_1', 'length_1', 'top_diam_1', 'base_diam_2', 'length_2', 'top_diam_2', 'base_diam_3', 'length_3', 'top_diam_3', 'x_product'], i='uniqueID', j='Tree Number', sep='_')
df3 = df2[df2['diameterbh'].notnull()].fillna(value=0)sort_values(by="Tree Number")
```

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE]?

Comment: @IanS I've added the code that I was working with. Does that help make the question clearer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit of code could be useful. You should indeed change the index to numeric before sorting. Be sure to update your dataframe, because by default pandas returns a copy of your dataframe. This works for me.

```
import pandas as pd

# you want to convert column a to index, and sort numerically
x = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['10', '2', '12', '1'], 'b': [100, 20, 120, 10]})
x.set_index('a', inplace=True) # Set the index (inplace to overwrite x)
x.index = x.index.astype(int)  # Make sure to change the index to a numeric type
x.sort_index(inplace=True)  # Again, inplace to prevent returning a copy
```

This makes x into a dataframe with a properly sorted index.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Quick extension to the question: what if I had a column 'c' : [c1, c2, c1, c2]. How do I ensure that the index arrangement is sorted according to index col a but clustered using col c ie. the output comes as: 'a': [10 , 12, 1, 2], 'c' [ c1, c1, c2, c2].

Comment: You can sort according to multiple columns with [`pandas.DataFrame.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html). The first argument, 'by' can accept a list. If you pass it a list, pandas first sorts by the first element, then the second and so forth.

So in your case, you should do sort_values before setting a as index. So first change a to numeric, then do `x.sort_values(by=['c', 'a'], inplace=True)` and then set a as index.